# What causes water to condense when air pressure is reduced?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, pressure, humidity

In this video: https://youtu.be/IyBRGhXBuGw

The cabin pressure is reduced and subsequently a mist is formed.

What exactly is the cause?

Comment: Consider what happens to the *temperature* of a gas as pressure is reduced. PV=nRT

Comment: Note that requests for video comments  are not very welcome. It is not critical here, as video is not even needed. But generally, the least you should do is providing the relevant video timestamp. Community readers are not really fans of watching videos to provide answers.

Comment: Please describe the content of the video and refer to it with creator and title. Links may die as videos get deleted, renamed, set private again, etc., and this question losses all context. Please [edit] accordingly. In its current state it should probably be closed.

Comment: See Gay-Lussac's Law.      https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay-Lussac's_law

Comment: I wrote "In this video [..] the cabin pressure is dropped and a mist is formed". How is that not a description? I'm not going to change it for no reason, so just close it, if that makes you happy.

Comment: honestly you lot need a day off lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing pressure causes temperature drop, as part of thermal energy of air is spent on mechanical work during air expansion.

That is why there is cold air at high altitudes. Air cools down by 1 °C when air  climbs 100 metres upwards until first condensation.

When temperature drops below the dew point, mist starts forming.